# Explain the following SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with the following table:

```
create table EmpDup(empid int,name varchar(20))

insert into EmpDup values(1,'Andy')

insert into EmpDup values (1,'Andy')

insert into EmpDup values(2,'Bill')

insert into EmpDup values(2,'Bill')

insert into EmpDup values (2,'Bill')

insert into EmpDup values (3,'Chris')
```

Table altered to add an identity column after inserting rows:

```
alter table EmpDup add  sno int identity(1,1)
```

Could someone please explain how the following query works?

```
select sno  from EmpDup D where 

1<(select count(*) from EmpDup A where A.empid=D.empid and A.name=D.name and 

D.sno>=A.sno)
```

I am not able to figure it out. It gives the following result:

> sno  2 4 5

Comment: What output were you expecting, and why?

Comment: Not really expecting any output...just not understanding how thr query works...not able to translate it to simple English in my head...

Answer (score 0):

Run this and you'll see that sno=2 appears twice, sno=4 appears twice and sno=5 appears 3 times.
The other values of sno only appear once so don't meet the count condition.

```
select D.empid, D.sno  from EmpDup D 
inner join EmpDup A on A.empid=D.empid and A.name=D.name and D.sno>=A.sno
```

Answer (score -2):

It returns the sno integer for the emp(loyees) that have more than one other sno integer.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If that's what it did, the three results would be the three `sno` IDs for 'Bill'. Two of them are, but not all three.

Comment: Almost, it returns the other rows but not the first one, because of `D.sno>=A.sno`